# Does bluebird have a convince function for wrapping functions in promises?

Tags: javascript, function, promise, bluebird

I have an object of functions. These functions aren't always fully promises.

For example:

```
function helloWorld(string){
  if(string == "foo") throw new Error("string is foo")
  return aPromise(string)
}
```

If the `string` is "foo" then this will throw an error that will not be caught with the `catch` call.

I'd rather write cleaner code like above instead of this:

```
function helloWorld(string){
  return Promise.resolve(){
    if(string == "foo") throw new Error("string is foo")
    return aPromise(string)
  }
}
```

So I created these functions that map over an object and add that nested `Promise.resolve`.

```
makePromises: function(obj){
  return _.mapObject(obj, function(fn){
    return function(){
      var args = _.values(arguments)
      return Promise.resolve().then(function(){
        return fn.apply(null, args)
      })
    }
  })
},
makeNestedPromises:function(obj){
  return _.mapObject(obj, function(fn){
    return function(){
      var args = _.values(arguments)
      var value = fn.apply(null, args)
      return function(){
        var args = _.values(arguments)
        return Promise.resolve().then(function(){
          return value.apply(null, args)
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I was wondering if this already existed natively within bluebird like `promisifyAll` but for seemingly synchronous functions (no callbacks), or if others found this useful.

So it seems that promisify does so this, just not with nested functions like I'd like.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")

var concat = function(one, two){
  return Promise.resolve(one + " " + two)
}

var fns = {}

fns.hello = function(name, rank){
  if(name == "tom") throw new Error("tom unauthorized")
  return concat(name, rank)
}

Promise.promisifyAll(fns)

fns.helloAsync("tom", "developer")
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log(e)
  })
```

This is what is broken:

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")

var concat = function(one, two){
  return Promise.resolve(one + " " + two)
}

var fns = {}

fns.hello = function(unauthorized){
  return function(name, rank){
    if(name == unauthorized) throw new Error("unauthorized")
    return concat(name, rank)
  }
}

Promise.promisifyAll(fns)

// here promisify thinks that the top level function should be a promise
fns.helloAsync("tom")("tom", "developer")
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log(e)
  })
```

Comment: possibly promisification? https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification

Comment: Promise.resolve also can take in the value returned by the function, so you can do Promise.resolve(fn.apply(...)) to get the result of a function as a promise.  This at least eliminates an unnecessary .then

Comment: Your second snippet seems to be a syntax error. Did you mean `return Promise.resolve().then(function(){ …; return …; })` or `return new Promise(function(resolve) { … resolve(…); })`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a `Promise.methodAll` with a `deep` optional parameter. Using`Promise.method` from @Bergi's answer.

```
var Promise = require("bluebird")
var _ = require("underscore")

Promise.methodAll = function(obj, deep){
  return _.mapObject(obj, function(fn){
    if(!deep) return Promise.method(fn)
    return function(){
      var nestedFn = fn.apply(null, _.values(arguments))
      return Promise.method(nestedFn)
    }
  })
}

var concat = function(one, two){
  return Promise.resolve(one + " " + two)
}

var deep = {}

deep.authorize = function(unauthorized){
  return function(name, rank){
    if(name == unauthorized) throw new Error("unauthorized")
    return concat(name, rank)
  }
}

deep = Promise.methodAll(deep, true)

var normal = {}

normal.authorize = function(name, rank){
  if(name == "tom") throw new Error("tom unauthorized")
  return concat(name, rank)
}

normal = Promise.methodAll(normal)

normal.authorize("tom", "developer")
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log(e) //[Error: tom unauthorized]
  })

deep.authorize("tom")("tom", "developer")
  .catch(function(e){
    console.log(e) //[Error: unauthorized]
  })
```

Comment: The point of `Promise.method` is that you shouldn't create such functions that only sometimes return promises in the first place. If a function is asynchronous, it should *always* return a promise (and `Promise.method` can help with that by simplifying syntax).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use [`Promise.method`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.method.html) for this:

```
var helloWorld = Promise.method(function helloWorld(string) {
  if(string == "foo") throw new Error("string is foo")
  return aPromise(string)
});
```

You should use promisification only for functions with asynchronous callbacks, it doesn't work on synchronous or promise-returning ones (even though it does catch synchronous exceptions).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no `Promise.methodAll` function that could wrap all of the functions in an object.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: `Promise.method` is supposed to be used only in the method definition itself, not to "promisify" foreign methods. What is your exact use case?

Comment: Check the answer below. My use case is that I'm creating a function that uses promises and I don't want to have to wrap every call in `Promise.resolve`.

Comment: This (Bergi's) is the correct usage of `Promise.method`.

Comment: @ThomasReggi: Right, you don't want to wrap every call in `Promise.resolve`, you want to wrap every *definition* that sometimes throws/returns synchronously in `Promise.method`.